# Scripting language which is not object oriented

Tags: oop, scripting-language

Is there any specific advantage to the scripting languages which are not Object-oriented?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Nothing specific, in general.

Comment: Well, depending on your goals, it might be that they don't support OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is "no" but really asking the questions means you just need to understand what "object oriented" means.  One of the easiest things for you might be to take scripting languages that have OO tacked onto them like Perl. [This is old but explains it nicely](http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/11/07/ooperl.html).

One of the simplest scripting languages I ever used that also is very useful IMHO is [TCL](http://www.tcl.tk/about/).  TCL programs typically do not use Object orientation, although it has an extension to do so for the die-hards :)

Comment: Perl is not an acronym. And `my` has nothing to do with OO. And Tcl has had object orientation in its core since 8.6 (and [incr Tcl] since 1993).

Comment: @CanSpice: So your position is that Perl couldn't possibly stand for "Patholically Eclectic Rubbish Lister" or "Practical Extraction and Report Language"? In case you care, Larry has been asked about whether it should be capitalized, and (typically) replied that it doesn't matter -- "there's more than one way to do it."

Comment: @Jerry: [You need to read the perldoc regarding Perl's name.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f)

Comment: @CanSpice: I've read it. What makes you think it has any real authority? For that matter, what makes you or them certain the expansions must be apocryphal and/or post-facto? The very first time I heard of Perl (early 1988), Larry personally gave both of the expansions I quoted above. Given the timing and obscurity of Perl at the time, it seems more likely to me that any post-facto editing is in the opposite direction, retracting the expansion, not adding it.

Comment: what's everyone up in arms about? want me to delete this answer? Is it the bless keyword?

Comment: PS CanSpice, I knew about incr TCL (mind you this was 1996) and thought it was an extension.. didn't realize it was totally integrated - but as an example of how to use a script language in a non-OO style, I thought it was a good example.